# Adding Header to Each Page of PDF in Node Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, pdfmerger

I am trying to print a header section to each page of a PDF that gets generated. I'm also using pdf-merger to merge together multiple PDFs. Right now when I execute this code the PDF generated contains multiple documents, as expected. However the `Header` section I'm adding only seems to show up in the 2nd and 5th of the documents that are part of the full PDF. I cannot tell from looking at my code why that is happening. I would assume the `Header` would be added to each of the documents.

First question: why am I noticing the behavior I am. Understand that would help me know what to adjust. Second question: How can I adjust this code so that the `Header` is added to each of the pages of the document?

Here is the section where I pass options to `page.pdf()`:

```
let doc = await page.pdf({
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  format: "A4",
  printBackground: true,
  headerTemplate: '<span style="font-size: 30px; width: 50px; height: 50px; color:black; margin: 20px;">Header</span>', 
});
```

And here is the full block of code:

```
let merger = new PDFMerger();

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    let recordNum = 1;
    for (let r of recordsArr) {
      try {
        let signatures = [];
        signatures = await signatureService.getSignatures({}, [r.guid]);
        if (signatures.length) r.signatureBase64Str = signatures[0].value;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return Response.Failure("Error occurred while obtaining signature.", err);
      }
      r.logoBase64Str = base64Logo;
      if (r.goalNotes.length) {
        for (const [i, value] of r.goalNotes.entries()) {
          value.number = i + 1;
        }
      }
      try {
        console.log(`processing record ${recordNum} of ${recordsArr.length}`);
        const content = await compile(r);
        await page.setContent(content);
        await page.emulateMediaType("screen");
        let doc = await page.pdf({
          displayHeaderFooter: true,
          format: "A4",
          printBackground: true,
          headerTemplate: '<span style="font-size: 30px; width: 50px; height: 50px; color:black; margin: 20px;">Header</span>', 
        });
        merger.add(doc);
        ++recordNum;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return Response.Failure("Unable to generate PDF by parameters passed.");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Much of this code calls functions I don't see defined anywhere. When I strip all of that out, it basically works for me. Can you provide a runnable [mcve] please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's wrong with your code since so many functions are undefined, but here's a minimal, runnable example that adds headers to all pages using the same PDF merger package as you:

```js
const PDFMerger = require("pdf-merger-js"); // ^4.3.0
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.4.1

const headerTemplate = `<span style="font-size: 30px; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: black; color: white; margin: 20px;">Header</span>`;
const mockContent = Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => `<div>page ${i}</div>`);
const filename = "merged.pdf";
const pdfSettings = {
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  format: "A4",
  printBackground: true,
  headerTemplate, 
  margin: {top: "100px", bottom: "100px"},
};

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const merger = new PDFMerger();

  for (const content of mockContent) {
    await page.setContent(content);
    merger.add(await page.pdf(pdfSettings));
  }

  await merger.save(filename);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```