# Combine multiple pdf using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I have generated multiple PDF using puppeteer and store the each pdf as buffer in one variable and then again use the puppeteer to combine all pdfs into single pdf.

```
async function combinePDFs(pdfBuffers) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: "new",
    args: [
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--font-render-hinting=none",
    ],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const combinedPDFBuff = Buffer.concat(pdfBuffers);

  await page.setContent(`<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,${combinedPDFBuff.toString('base64')}" type="application/pdf" />`, {
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
  });
  await page.emulateMediaType('screen');
  await page.setViewport({
      width: 1200,
      height: 800
    });


  const combinedPDFBuffer = await page.pdf({
    format: 'A4',
    printBackground: true,
    preferCSSPageSize: true,
  });
  await browser.close();

  return combinedPDFBuffer

}
```

and then send it to frontend.

```
 const combineResultBuff =  await combinePDFs(pdfBuff)
  console.log("object",combineResultBuff);
  res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/pdf");
  res.send(combineResultBuff)
```

but when I try to consume it in front end

```
 const config = {
  url: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL + `/order/way_bill_generate`,
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    secret_key: process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY,
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
  responseType: "blob",
  data: {
    data: saveData,
  },
};
setLoading(true)

try {
  const wayBill = await axios(config);
  const blob = new Blob([wayBill.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  setPDFUrl(url);
setLoading(false)
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
setLoading(false)
}
```

};

it gives me an empty pdf.
Can anyone help.

Comment: Probably the combined pdf was not generated correctly

Comment: I wouldn't have used pupeeteer to combine the pdf anyway, may be `pdf-merger-js`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67914165/6243352) may help (using `PDFMerger` with Puppeteer).

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is the  tag can you try and use the below instead of the embed tag

```
await page.setContent(`
    <html>
      <body>
        <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,${combinedPDFBuff.toString('base64')}" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
      </body>
    </html>`, {
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
  });
```

Comment: not working I have tried